# Can i override default form submitting method "POST" with another "POST" method?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I want to change the default `post` method of `form submitting` to another `post` method to change the way that the default method behaves like refreshing the whole page etc...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your question in quite unclear... could you add more details to it maybe with some concrete HTML/JS examples?

Comment: Yes, this is done all the time, like when using AJAX instead of submitting the form. Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a global event listener for submit events that checks the method of the form it was invoked on. If it is a POST submission, you can prevent the default behaviour and do something else.

```js
addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.method.toLowerCase() === "post") {
    evt.preventDefault();
    alert("Do something else now");
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I understand AJAX but could you pls mention in that case what is the difference between the two post methods conceptually `AJAX` and `default form submit` , what makes AJAX calls do not refresh the page, i mean are they different post methods implementations or they are identical post methods that is handled differently?

Comment: A POST request is just an HTTP request which has the POST method in the header. You can create a POST request by submitting a form with method=POST, by using JavaScript with the XMLHttpRequest object, on the command line with `curl`, in a developer's app like Postman, and so on. "Ajax" is just a buzzword meaning "Making an HTTP request using JavaScript wihtout leaving the page".